# How to execute useLazyQuery programmatically?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

Ok, I understand React Apollo's `useLazyQuery` executes only once its first argument is called. But I was disappointed to learn that after that it behaves like `useQuery`.

So: How to control when `useLazyQuery` fires? My use case is pretty simple: I have an 'autocomplete' search bar. I don't want to query when the input is empty. I can easily do that on first 'emptiness', but I can't find a way to disable the query when the user deletes the whole input.

Comment: If all you need is to not run the query when the input is an empty string, I would imagine `useQuery` would be sufficient. You can set the `skip` parameter to `R.isEmpty(str)` to skip the query when the string is empty.

Comment: That works too!

Answer (score 3):

Ok found the answer even before I posted :)

Looks like if your query has variables, Apollo Client won't run it until you supply them. So for my use case:

```
const [execQuery, {data}] = useLazyQuery (QUERY_SEARCH)
useEffect (() => {
  str && (() => {
    execQuery ({variables: {str}})
  })()
}, [str])

const results = R.isEmpty (str) ? null : data
```

Comment: So the docs could be improved (to say it a good way). After execution, useLazyQuery behaves like useQuery *if* variables have been supplied with the call to `useLazyQuery`. Otherwise you can control execution as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go ahead and steal @Daniel's answer :)

The following code accomplishes the goal

```
const

skip = R.complement (H.isNotNilOrEmpty) (str),

{data} = useQuery (QUERY_SEARCH, {variables: {str}, skip}),
```

sorry for using undefined variables R and H but hopefully the method names are descriptive